# Multiple Query Values in Get Request to JSON based Express Api

Tags: json, node.js, rest, express, lodash

I have followed this tutorial https://jonathanmh.com/building-a-simple-searchable-api-with-express-backend/. However I can't seem to get it to work even when I copy the source code. I'm not sure if I have done something wrong that I have missed. Basically when using 2 query parameters I get all the records returned in the response. It works with one fine. The api route is

```
app.get('/api/stores', function(req, res){
  var response = [];
  console.log(req.query)

  // this would usually adjust your database query
   if(typeof req.query.nsfw != 'undefined'){
     stores.filter(function(store){
      if(store.nsfw.toString() == req.query.nsfw){
       response.push(store);
      }
     });
   } 

 // this would usually adjust your database query
  if(typeof req.query.location != 'undefined'){
    stores.filter(function(store){
      if(store.location === req.query.location){
       response.push(store);
     }
    });
   }

  // de-duplication:
    response = _.uniqBy(response, 'id');

  // in case no filtering has been applied, respond with all stores
    if(Object.keys(req.query).length === 0){
     response = stores;
   }

   res.json(response);
   });
```

The JSON file is

```
    const stores = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Hollows End Grim Potions',
    imageURL: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465433360938-e02f97448763?    auto=format&fit=crop&w=1267&q=60&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D',
    location: 'Hollows End',
    nsfw: true
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Lembas Food Truck',
    imageURL:      'https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/DHHQbqc0RrWVf0uDNe5E_The%20Litte%20Cafe.jpg?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1489&q=60&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D',
location: 'Lothlorien',
nsfw: false
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Galadriels Mirror of Brutal Truth',
    imageURL: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1497519098947-a305f214d3bc?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=60&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D',
    location: 'Lothlorien',
    nsfw: true
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Jabbas Light Sabers',
     imageURL: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1481241857164-e8483bce922d?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1353&q=60&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D',
    location: 'Mos Eisley',
    nsfw: true
   }
 ];

module.exports = stores;
```

So to reiterate my question- why if I place http://localhost:3000/api/stores?location=Lothlorien&nsfw=true do I not only get id:3? Right now I get all records returned.

EDIT:

I just tried it with http://localhost:3000/api/stores?location=Lothlorien&nsfw=false and I strangely get two records ID:2 & ID:3 when I should only be getting ID:2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're filtering on the conditions separately and pushing the results of each onto your `response` array instead of using `&&` to filter both conditions together.

For example when filtering on `location=Lothlorien` OR `nsfw=true`, you get 2 results for the location and 3 for the nsfw which uniquely includes 4 (all of them). However, if it had to meet both criteria together, you'd expect to get 1 result - only 1 location named Lothlorien that has nsfw of false.

Here's an example using `&&`:

```
const { location=null, nsfw=null } = req.query;
if (location && nsfw) {
  stores.filter((store) => {
    if(store.nsfw.toString() === nsfw && store.location === location){
      response.push(store);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Great, that makes sense. Although I did copy the tutorial to the letter so I guess the guy needs to update it. I will need to go now and figure out how to use && in this situation. Thx

Comment: I added an example to use `&&`. Let me know if it helps or you have questions.

Comment: Thank you sir, that is just what I needed!

Comment: @PaulLeppard The tutorial is good (I read it too), what the author wants is display the values that have Lothlorien  as location or nsfw as true. If you notice there will not be a response with nsfw false and another location that is not Lothlorien.

Answer (score 1):

I got here via the link to this page in the comment of the article.  I too was wanting the server code to behave differently, so I fiddled around with this a bit and got the results I was looking for.  I hope this answers the Original Posters' question.  Here is my entire server.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const stores = require('./data/stores');
//  npm i express-query-boolean
const boolParser = require('express-query-boolean');

app.use(boolParser());

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!')
});

app.get('/api/stores', function (req, res) {
    let response = [];
    const q = req.query;  // Query object
    if (Object.keys(q).length === 0) {
        // NO query parameters, send it all...
        response = stores;
    } else {
        // We have a query, filter response to match request
        response = stores.filter(function (store) {
            return Object.keys(this).every((key) => store[key] === this[key]);
        }, q);
    }
    res.json(response);
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```